# How to Customize UITabBar - On selection of tabbar how to change the image of selected tabbar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

How to change image on selection of tab bar. Help me out on this Thank you.

Comment: Better You search a bit more, this question have been asked many times in last month.

Answer (score 1):

You can find here about how to create Custom Tab bar

http://www.rumexit.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/

And you can follow the Code below for Setting Images & Image Selected for UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateSelected

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Normal.png"];
UIImage *btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bouton_Selected.png"];

self.bouton_tab = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; //Setup the button
bouton_tab.frame = CGRectMake(xStart, TABYSTART, TABITEMWIDTH, TABITEMHEIGHT); // Set the frame (size and position) of the button)
[bouton_tab setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Set the image for the normal state of the button
[bouton_tab setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected]; // Set the image for the selected state of the button
[bouton_tab setTag:0]; // Assign the button a "tag" so when our "click" event is called we know which button was pressed.
[bouton_tab setSelected:true]; // Set this button as selected (we will select the others to false as we only want Tab 1 to be selected initially
```

I hope, this helps you lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITabBarControllerDelegate method

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   if(tabBarController.selectedIndex==0)
   {
      [viewController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]];
   }
}
```

use this code in appDelegate.m file
and add a protocol in appDelegate.h file

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom tab bar:
 1. Create tab bar view controller
 2. In this VC put this method:

```
-(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage
{
    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    self.button.center = self.tabBar.center;

    [self.view addSubview: self.button];

}
```

In your tab bar controller `viewDidLoad` call this method from that way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self addCenterButtonWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bemobile.png"] highlightImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bemobileSelected.png"]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Where in `highlightImage` you pass the image that will be shown when you select that tab bar item

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try this one, hope this will help,

I have change the selected tabbatitem image like -

in tabbar controller delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{
    if([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 0)
    {
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
    }    
}
```

through this you can change your image.

Or you can use directly in your view controllers init(or ViewWillAppear) method, like

```
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
```